# Why "him" in "For neuer resting time leads Summer on / To hidious winter and confounds him there, ..." instead of it or her?

Tags: pronouns, early-modern-english, shakespeare, literary-english, grammatical-gender

There is a passage in [William's V sonnet](https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/Son_Q1/section/Sonnet%204~Sonnet%206/index.html)  that confounds me :

*For neuer resting time leads Summer on,*

*To hidious winter and confounds **him** there,*

*Sap checkt with frost and lustie leau's quite gon.*

***Him*** is also present in the version of sonnet V with modernized spellings. Why? I was looking for an answer in the Web, but [the research I found](https://www.enotes.com/topics/william-shakespeare/critical-essays/margareta-de-grazia-university-pennsylvania) focuses on "scandalous" aspect of pronouns in William's sonnets.

Comment: Summer is personified. Note the word is commenced with a capital letter.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Would Shakespeare get away with 'him' nowadays?

Comment: Poets often use (um) poetic language.  Even today.

Comment: Edwin - I don't see why not. Summer, my bright warm friend/Has warned me of his impending end. I just made that up. Looks fine to me, but then I suppose it would.

Comment: Spring, that sweet young girl/Her fresh new charms will soon unfurl. I could get to like doing this.